# Spring Boot WebFlux Kotlin no routes found

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I faced problem that I can't add route to spring context. I tried to do this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<TestApp>(*args) {
        addInitializers(beans {
            bean {
                RoutesConfig().router()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and my route is

```
@Configuration
class RoutesConfig {

    fun router() = router {
        GET("/health") { _ -> ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromObject("OK")) }
    }
}
```

I tried to add `@Bean` annotation, tried via `SpringApplication.run()`, tried via different variants of configuration including `BeanInitializers` - nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

```
2019-05-21 21:17:04.752  INFO 7785 --- [           main] c.p.i.s.manager.TestAppKt      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-21 21:17:05.333  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-05-21 21:17:05.345  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.345  INFO 7785 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-05-21 21:17:05.349  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/adm/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.404  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-21 21:17:05.404  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 630 ms
2019-05-21 21:17:05.420  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.423  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.423  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.423  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.423  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-21 21:17:05.568  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-21 21:17:05.733  WARN 7785 --- [           main] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=12, workerCount=12}
2019-05-21 21:17:05.734  WARN 7785 --- [           main] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: PooledConnectionProvider {name=http, poolFactory=reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$$Lambda$378/429639728@4d8286c4}
2019-05-21 21:17:05.841  INFO 7785 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-21 21:17:05.844  INFO 7785 --- [           main] c.p.i.s.manager.TestAppKt      : Started TestAppKt in 1.495 seconds (JVM running for 2.14)
```

Comment: everything looks fine. please provide more information. error stuck, spring boot version your using, etc.

Comment: @Vinipuh007 spring boot version 2.1.0-RELEASE, no errors, just browser said that there is no such endpoint. If I declare controller in old way via `@Controller` - everything looks fine

Comment: Can you attach console output of the server startup?

Comment: @Vinipuh007added

Comment: that's weird. I tried to reproduce it but everything works fine on my side

Comment: Do you have any special configuration beside tomcat container?

Comment: @Vinipuh007 no only classes I shared with you. Maybe there is the problem that my spring boot is 2.1.0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193722/discussion-between-vinipuh007-and-squeez).